# Making my method return a string

Tags: java, string, methods, return

I am trying to make a program to deal you a hand of cards that I randomly generate. For some reason I can't get it to print the string from my method in the main program. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if it's all just wrong, I'm rather new to the java scene. this is what I got.

```
public class Deck {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Builder();
    out.println("Your hand is:" card )
  }
  // This will build the deck
  public static String Builder() {
    // I need this to pick from the random array
    Random r = new Random();

    // This is an array, to make one you need [] before string
    //This is how you get your ending
    String[] SuitsA = { "Hearts ",  "Diamonds ", "Spades ", "Clubs" };
    // The number array
    String[] FaceA = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","King ", "Queen ", "Jack ", "Ace ",};

    // Picks a random set from the arrays 
    String suit = SuitsA[r.nextInt(4)]; 
    String face = FaceA[r.nextInt(14)];

    //Tryng to make 1 string to return
    String card = ( suit + " of " + face ); 
    // This might give me a value to use in the method below
    out.println( card );
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  For future reference, you may want to tag your questions with the language you are using.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, since your are returning nothing from a method that clearly states to return a `String`.  Use an IDE (such as Eclipse) to avoid simple issues like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning your calculate card value (string) from your method. So return that string like this

```
 String card = ( suit + " of " + face ); 
    // This might give me a value to use in the method below
 return card;
```

and use it in `main` method

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
String value=Builder();
out.println("Your hand is:"+ value )
}
```